# Microservices architecture and tools to use with SpringBoot

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have been researching and working on a personal project using Java SpringBoot in a Microservices architecture, but I have seen many different tutorials using many different tools.

I have seen most tutorials use Zuul Proxy and routing, Eureka, Feign, Ribbon, etc. So my question is, what each of those components is responsible for, when, why, and how I should implement those components in my project?

Comment: My friend, your question is very vague. If you have already gone through tutorials and implemented in your project then i think you should not have so many queries like what each component does. Kindly post a specific question pertaining you impedance you are facing